# Probability that the first number is strictly greater than the second

Tags: probability

*This is a nice problem on Probability. I request you all to please help me with the same.*

*Problem -*

A number consists of three distinct digits chosen at random from $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ and $9$ and then arranged in descending order. A second number is constructed in the same way except that the digit 9 is not be used. What is the probability that the first number is strictly greater than the second number?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: I was making up cases for it ... like first I took the hundreds digit as 9 for the first number and 8 for the second. Then 9 for the first and 7 for the second. Similarly I later took 8 for the first number and 8 for the second but then moved on to the next digit (i.e. the ten's digit.) I continued on with the same but I thought it was a very long task to be done. I wonder if there is a shorter solution for it ... I hope you get what I am trying to explain by my method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: The first number is guaranteed larger if $9$ is one of the three digits chosen (because the sorting will put it first, i.e. in the hundreds place).  So you can just condition on this event.

- What is the prob that $9$ is one of the three digits chosen?
- Conditioned on $9$ being not chosen, what is the prob that the first number is strictly greater than the second?
- Apply the law of total probability.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I got what you wanted to say

Comment: @gamerrk1004 you're welcome.  Just be careful of the 2nd bullet because you need "strictly greater".